# Analyse 10 min interval data every 30 minutes in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have 24-hour data sampled at 1 min intervals. I need to subtract min data from max data row every 30 minutes, i.e. 00:00 - 00:10 (max - min) ; 00:30 - 00:40 (max - min)  ....

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
```

```
ts = ['25/02/2023 0:00', '25/02/2023 0:01', '25/02/2023 0:02', '25/02/2023 0:03', '25/02/2023 0:04', '25/02/2023 0:05', '25/02/2023 0:06', '25/02/2023 0:07', 
        '25/02/2023 0:08', '25/02/2023 0:09', '25/02/2023 0:10', '25/02/2023 0:11', '25/02/2023 0:12', '25/02/2023 0:13', '25/02/2023 0:14', '25/02/2023 0:15', 
        '25/02/2023 0:16', '25/02/2023 0:17', '25/02/2023 0:18', '25/02/2023 0:19', '25/02/2023 0:20', '25/02/2023 0:21', '25/02/2023 0:22', '25/02/2023 0:23', 
        '25/02/2023 0:24', '25/02/2023 0:25', '25/02/2023 0:26', '25/02/2023 0:27', '25/02/2023 0:28', '25/02/2023 0:29', '25/02/2023 0:30', '25/02/2023 0:31',
        '25/02/2023 0:32', '25/02/2023 0:33', '25/02/2023 0:34', '25/02/2023 0:35', '25/02/2023 0:36', '25/02/2023 0:37', '25/02/2023 0:38', '25/02/2023 0:39',
        '25/02/2023 0:40', '25/02/2023 0:41', '25/02/2023 0:42', '25/02/2023 0:43', '25/02/2023 0:44', '25/02/2023 0:45']

temp = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71']

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(ts, ‘temp’)),
                  columns = ['ts', 'temp'])
```

which prints:

```
             ts                       temp
0    2023-02-25 00:00:00              7.189607
1    2023-02-25 00:01:00              7.185260
2    2023-02-25 00:02:00              7.180914
3    2023-02-25 00:03:00              7.176567
4    2023-02-25 00:04:00              7.172220
...                  ...                   ...
1436 2023-02-25 23:56:00              7.661235
1437 2023-02-25 23:57:00              7.623201
```

Comment: Look into `pd.rolling`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you want, and it's hard to answer when you don't provide a script that can reproduce the issue without having to generate data, but hopefully this helps (also note you'll need to move ts to the index, i.e. `df = df.set_index('ts'`). Also I think you need to apply two windows (one to aggregate 1min -> 10min and as second to take the first window every 30 minutes - I took a shortcut and just used a filter for the second requirement)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# generate synthetic data
ts = pd.date_range(start='2023-02-1', end='2023-02-2', freq='1T')
df = pd.DataFrame({'SCADA__MW': np.random.randn(len(ts))}, index=ts)

# generate min/max every 10 minutes
df = df.rolling(10, step=10).agg(['min', 'max'])

# apply a 30-minute window to the aggregate and take the first value?
df = df[df.index.minute.isin([10,40])]
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks- awesome! However how do I only keep the min & max for first 10 mins from every 30 minutes please? i.e. at 00:10,  00:40, 01:10, 01:40...

Comment: That's what the last line does (or was supposed to). I left off the assignment which I've fixed. Basically, it's filtering so that the minutes are either 40 or 10. Note my code requires that you don't have gaps and start at 00:00 - I'm not 100% sure how to create a window in pandas using a freq (i.e. `10T`) that has a step, I tend to use polars more now.

Comment: I'd have to think about that a bit, basically you want to first create 30 minute strided windows (`rolling(30, step=30)`) then take the first 13 from each window and then apply the aggregate.